# Detect a Collision, not a Contact in Box2D

Tags: android, box2d, collision-detection, andengine, physics

First, let me define how I perceive these two concepts:

**Collision** happens when *Object A* **collides/bumps/runs into** *Object B*. As in they come into contact with each other, but with a high velocity.

**Contact** happens when *Object A* **touches** *Object B*. As in they come into contact with [very] low velocity. As in they just touch.

In **Box2D**, we assign `ContactListener`s to the `PhysicsSystem` in order to detect a contact. My question is, **how do we detect a collision**?

I'm using *AndEngine* in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the relative velocity of the two bodies in the BeginContact function of the contact listener.

Comment: Is there nothing like a method I can call?

Comment: No. It's just (bodyA.getLinearVelocity() - bodyB.getLinearVelocity()).Length(). See http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy for more info